Do people in the Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse series notice that people are drawn in different animation/art styles?
In both movies in the franchise, every universe has its own animation and art style.
Do people realise that other people look/“move” (in respect to animation) differently?
For example, in the second movie, when Spot peeks into the LEGO universe, does Spot notice that everyone is LEGO, and vice versa?

They certainly notice when they're all standing around together. "Wow, you're black and white", etc.

Yes, characters do notice the different art styles.
In the Spider-Verse series, characters are indeed aware of the varying animation and art styles representing different universes. This is explicitly shown in the first movie, Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse, when Miles Morales encounters Spider-Man Noir for the first time.


Spider-Man Noir: Hey, fellas.
Miles: Is he in black and white?

